# Spring MVC + RestController gives 406 for resources

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, http-status-code-406

i am configuring my project for a small rest app.
I am using Spring 4.2.2.RELEASE
I have a problem when i create a controller annotated with @RestController or I add @ResponseBody. The css or js resources just stop working and send the error 406 Not aceptable. I read that it is dued to the message converter, but i still have the problem.

Thanks in advance

My config.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>${log4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- postgres -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>${postgresql.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSON -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        <version>${jackson.version}</version>
    </dependency>

<!--        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
        <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>-->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JSP -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <!--commentar para tomcat -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
        <!--commentar para tomcat -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <!--commentar para tomcat -->
        <!-- <scope>provided</scope> -->
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.encuestas</groupId>
        <artifactId>encuestas-service</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.encuestas</groupId>
        <artifactId>encuestas-data</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Spring config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@PropertySource("classpath:/app.properties")
@ComponentScan
@Import({SpringJpaConfig.class})
public class SpringMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureContentNegotiation(ContentNegotiationConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.favorPathExtension(true)
                .ignoreAcceptHeader(true)
                .defaultContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .mediaType("json", MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
    }
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertyPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```

the controller

```
@RestController
public class EmpresaApiController {

    @Autowired
    private EmpresaService empresaService;

    @RequestMapping(name = "/api/empresa", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<EmpresaBean> listAll() {
        return empresaService.listAll();
    }

}
```

If I comment the function listAll from EmpresaApiController, it works just fine. But if I add it, the css and js does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Force the resource handler to take higher precedence than `RequestMapping`

```
@Override
public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    registry.setOrder(-1);
}
```